# Will the saturation current through one of these NMOS circuits always be greater than the other?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, nmos, vlsi, device

Is there a definitive way to know for all cases if an NMOS would have a greater saturation current if a resistor R is connected to 1) the drain side or 2) the source side?

The assumption is that the devices are identical and operate in saturation with VDD and GND connections as given in the picture.

I am looking for DC analysis only. Any mathematical or even intuitive answers will really be appreciated!

[image: Drawn Circuit]

Comment: This looks like a homework question, so we expect you to show that you have put substantial effort into solving the problem yourself. So, what do you think the answer will be?

Comment: A small hint to help guide you to discovering a solution for yourself - suppose a current of some fixed value does flow. You know that Vgs is important in a FET in saturation - what happens to the Vgs of the left circuit? What about the right circuit?

Comment: Consider when the gate-source voltage is driven not from VDD but from a battery connected between the gate and source. What happens when you don't drive it from the battery, but from VDD?

Comment: For an NMOS device, if Vdd >> Vgth, then the left hand FET is on and there is ~= Vdd across R. The right hand FET has somewhat less than (Vdd-Vgsth) across the resistor.

Comment: @NoobFlop - Elliot's comment is legitimate. If a question appears to be homework or similar we still help but take a more "didactic" approach. We wih to help people to learn.  Advising if it is or isnt homework or similar is a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

In the second case for R >> RdsOn Vds = Vt  so I=(Vdd-Vt)/R and neglect RdsOn  , otherwise for smaller R, I increases up to limit of Vdd/RdsOn.

In the 1st case Vgs is reduced by Is*R so if R >> RdsOn then the limiting current is the current used to rate the threshold Vt which is usually 100 uA or so.

Otherwise for smaller R current is increased up to the maximum of Vdd/RdsOn or it is reduced by the square root of (Vdd-Vt). Since  Ids = beta * 1/2 * (Vgs - Vt)^2.